# How do I turn off formatting for .js files in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Is there a way to disable source formatting for just *.js files in Xcode?  The formatter absolutely mangles my javascript files, but I don't want to lose the functionality for Objective-C file.

Comment: I would recommend using a different IDE for JS (or just a plain old text editor like TextWrangler), as XCode isn't designed for this.

Comment: I typically do, but if I need to make a small change to a .js file in the context of working with native code I'd like to not be bothered by having to leave Xcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable the crazy javascript auto-indentation by going to

Preferences -> Text Editing -> Indentation

and unchecking "Syntax-aware indenting".

This disables auto-indentation for all languages, not just .js files.  If you're doing lots of javascript or don't mind needing to hit the tab key to indent, it might be worth it.

Comment: I think this is unfortunately the best I can hope for =[

Answer (score 8):

What worked fairly well for me is to switch the .js files to use C syntax coloring.

In XCode 4: Editor -> Syntax Coloring -> C

It still highlights numbers and strings and comments, and it indents braces in a sane way.

Answer (score 1):

I have XCode 4.6.1 and I was able to keep syntax coloring by going to

XCode -> Preferences... -> Text Editing -> Indentation

and just unchecking **Automatic indent for: ";"** (semicolon).

I was able to keep other syntax-aware indenting turned on, and got pretty good results.